# Soql query field value starts with

Tags: apex, soql

How to retrieve account records where the name starts with "comp"?

Select Id,Name From Account Where Name Like 'comp%'

Does the above query guarantee at least 4 characters in length?

Comment: Yes it will. It will retrieve all records in the Account object that have a Name that starts with `comp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the expression 'comp%' will bring everything that starts with 'comp' and ends with anything

if you want to always guarantee 4 letters after 'comp' you can use it as follows LIKE 'comp____' use 4 underscore to ensure 4 characters after 'comp'

Comment: perfect exactly what I was looking for